# Dynamic dropdown list without ASP.NET

Tags: list, dynamic

I want to create something like that:

3.bp.blogspot.com/-RlGu3mmu6jA/URJdWWtt9XI/AAAAAAAADoU/ryaRZ3DKkzc/s1600/1.gif

but without ASP.NET.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: If you have only a couple possible options then you can easily do that with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you can easily use client-side code such as Javascript.

Here is an example using Javascript and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ET5JW/9/

HTML:

```
<label for="firstBox">First Select</label>
<select id="firstBox">
    <option value="">Select Option...</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="secondBox_frame" style="display:none;">
    <label for="secondBox">Second Select</label>
    <select id="secondBox">
        <option value="">Use first box first</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
var options = new Array("a","b");
options["a"] = new Array("1a","2a","3a");
options["b"] = new Array("1b","2b","3b");

$("#firstBox").change(function(){
    if ($("#firstBox").val()) {
        $("#secondBox").html('');
        var selectedOptions = options[$("#firstBox").val()];
        for (var i in selectedOptions) {
            $("#secondBox").append('<option value="'+selectedOptions[i]+'">'+selectedOptions[i]+'</option>');                         
        }
        $("#secondBox_frame").fadeIn(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#secondBox").html('<option value="">Use first box first</option>');
        $("#secondBox_frame").fadeOut(400);
    }
});
```

If you are interested in doing this server-side [PHP](http://www.php.net/) could help.

Comment: Thanks so much, just what I was after. Is it possible to display the second dropdown list only after the first dropdown list was used?

Comment: @user3433505, I updated it to include the show/hide you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible somehow?

yes, um ... but what language do you want to use? do you want something like that for a web page ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949327/conditional-dropdownlist-using-jquery-or-javascript-only))? or in an desktop programm (e.g. [java - swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542408/options-in-second-combobox-dependent-on-first-combobox))? android/iOS app ?